# How to fix: InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement with Ionic 4/5

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-api

I have this error that I can not solve, actively sought on ionic forum and on Stackoverflow but nothing works.
I’m trying to implement the google places API in the ion-search-bar.

I've made this tutorial: https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete
Thank you in advance for your help.

tab1.page.html

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Adresse / Parcelle" autocomplete mode="md" class="searchbar"
    matInput
    matGoogleMapsAutocomplete
    [country]="de"
    (onAutocompleteSelected)="onAutocompleteSelected($event)"
    (onLocationSelected)="onLocationSelected($event)">
   </ion-searchbar>
```

tab1.module.ts

```
export class Tab1PageModule implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let input = document.getElementById('autocomplete').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    let options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use the getInputElement Method of the ion component. It will return the native ELEMENT you can use.

1. Put a `#mysearch` on your `ionSearch`, then you will need to define it:

   `@ViewChild("mySearch",{static:false}) searchElementRef: IonSearch**Bar**; (remember to 
   import IonSearchBar!!!)`
2. In your method: use the provided getInputElement() from ionic which returns the native component.

   ```
   this.searchElementRef.getInputElement().then((input:HTMLInputElement)=>{
       var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
       types: ["geocode"]


       });
   )
   ```
3. You can use this for ion-input too!

Comment: replace "coladdress" with "mysearch", I just copied that from my other project.

Comment: And the correct term is now IonSearchbar not IonSearch :)

Comment: You can use [edit] link below your answer to make changes instead of adding info as comments